# Solve By Using Logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$3^x=3^{3x+1}$
Solve By Using Logarithms. I've tried flipping it so it's Log base 3 of $3x+1$, but i do not know what is next.
The answer is $x = 0$, but i need to show my work.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This will help understanding for example if you mean $3^3x + 1$ or $3^{3x} + 1$ or even $3^{3x+1}$. For the moment nobody can say.

Comment: $\large t \equiv 3^{x}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin, why substitute? why not taking ln both sides?it will reduce to $x=3x+1$, pls tell me if I am missing something.

Comment: How is the answer $x=0$? If you plug in to the equation, you'll get $$3^{(0)}=3^{3(0)+1}$$ which implies $1=3$, which is not true.

Comment: @Vikram A few minutes ago, the $\large 1$ was not in the exponent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$3^x=3^{3x+1}$$

$$\log_3 3^x=\log _3 3^{3x+1}$$
$$x=3x+1$$
$$2x+1=0$$

$$x=-\frac{1}{2}$$